# Laravel Queue download file using CURL

Tags: php, laravel, curl, pentaho, laravel-queue

I'm trying to generate the file using curl. When I try executing the command via terminal it works fine.

[image]

But when I try to implement it on laravel using a queue, the script runs but the downloaded file is corrupt.

[image]

As you can see from the "Time Spent" it doesn't even have value compared to the one executed from terminal. And the file is there but obviously corrupt since laravel already finished the command even before it started.

Here's my code on the `handle()` function of GeneratBukuVot Job:

```
$path = Storage::path('public/test.pdf');

$pentaho =  'http://192.168.0.17:8080/pentaho/api/repos/:home:admin:anggaran_hasil_and_belanja_param.prpt/generatedContent?output-target=pageable/pdf&search_year=2019';
    $cmd = 'curl -u"admin:password" "'.$pentaho.'" -o "'.$path.'"';
    $output = shell_exec($cmd);
```

I'm using Laravel version 5.8. Please, help.

Comment: Why are you trying to execute it as shell command ? PHP supports cURL

Comment: Less line & more simple. I tried the curl php method but the result is still the same.

Comment: I personally use rmccue/requests package, i feel like that would suit your needs too